# What is needed to create an online Compiler for android?

Tags: java, android, xml-rpc, rpc

I searched for a method to call the compiler for Java from a website, consider it as online compiler.  What I want to do is specify the layout of UIs of the application through a website, after that I want to call Android SDK (or compiler) to compile an existing app with new layouts that I provide it.

I would like to know the basic principles and approach to creating something like this.

Comment: What about that? http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html

Comment: do you mean, that I can execute cmd from PHP ( for example ) and sendcommands related to Android through cmd console

Comment: thats what i meant but keep in mind that it's difficult to create a multi user system out of it.

Comment: because compilers tend to be very cpu intensive so you need a smart architecture if you want to serve multiple users at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to design and compile remotely, I'd suggest a remote access service, like XVnc (for Linux), Remote Desktop or LogMeIn (for Windows).

Comment: I will have a website , and on the back end I will have the SDK , I want to call the android compiler though the website

Comment: I want to create web interface for android SDK and complier